# Nuxt3 useFetch only retrieving data occasionally

Tags: vue.js, strapi, nuxtjs3, nuxt-strapi

I'm a little bit confused with Nuxt 3 and the lifecycle of when it gets data. I understand that it's a universal rendering process, but I'm using Strapi 4 to manage content in my Nuxt 3 project and only occasionally do I retrieve the data via useFetch. The API route from Strapi never goes down so I'm probably just doing something wrong.

Here is my Vue file in Nuxt:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const {data: works, pending, error} = await useFetch("http://localhost:1337/api/works", {
  params: {
    populate: "*"
  }
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="work in works">
        ... do something
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I'm not sure how to get the content when the page loads. When I log the error returned, it's just `true`. But it's only sometimes. The content will load once, and then as soon as I refresh the page, it goes back to having an error. So I'm thinking something is getting cached maybe client-side? I'm really not sure what to do next.

Comment: I'm thinking that it's something with the Strapi API URL now, maybe localhost has a rate limit or something? I made a random fetch request and it works every time so I'm thinking that it's something with localhost, maybe?

Comment: I think I'm having the same issue, what I believe it is, is that when it tries to load it on the server it fails because its not a secure request and its to another domain

Comment: if there is a way to pass httpAgent to useFetch could solve this problem pretty easily

Comment: @ThePaxBisonica  Did either of you resolve this issue? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I don't believe so, I just started using sanity instead since that is hosted with a certificate for me

Answer (score 1):

Try passing this option to useFetch: `initialCache: false`. [See more](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/use-fetch)

Answer (score 1):

Why not using Strapi module for Nuxt3?
It handles all these issues.
https://strapi.nuxtjs.org/setup

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).